# Wordpress Connect to SmartSheet via REST/JSON/Auth

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to make a WordPress site that will use data from SmartSheet. I need to Authenticate(Authorization) to get into SmartSheet. SS uses an API Access token to get access. All of this works fine in postman. My question is: Are there plugins for this? Or should I be writing a plugin for this? Any good resources for this?

Answer (score -2):

There is no official WordPress connector from Smartsheet.